# R match.fun does not see function from imported package

Tags: r, function, match

I've imported package called "stabledist". It includes function "rstable"

When I do this

```
my_fun <- function(function_from_library)
{
  function_from_library <- match.fun(function_from_library)
  print(some_data <- function_from_library)
}

my_fun (5, rstable(5, alpha = 1.7, beta = 0, gamma = 1.0, delta = 1.0))
```

I get error:" Error in match.fun(some_distr) : 'rstable(5, alpha = 1.7, beta = 0, gamma = 1, delta = 1)' is not a function, character or symbol "

Everything works fine, whrn match.fun is deleted. Is there anyway to import library that it can be visible to others? Or I can just skip match.fun?

Comment: I think `match.fun` wants an actual function, not a call to one. Your example is simple, certainly, but it isn't clear what you are really intending to do here. As an example, you define `my_fun` with one argument but call it with two.

Comment: The idea is to use distribution from package for some Monte-Carlo simulation. So main function should take trials as argument and distribution. Because I want to change distributions, I want to pass into my_fun some function_from_library, because each of them take different arguments I cant specify

Comment: Use `rstable` (no parentheses, no arguments). Then give the arguments to `function_from_library`.

Comment: which you'd typically do with the ellipses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I implemented my suggestion:

```
 library(stabledist )
 my_fun <- function(function_from_library, ...)
 {
   function_from_library <- match.fun(function_from_library)
   print(some_data <- function_from_library(...))
 }

 my_fun ( rstable, 5, alpha = 1.7, beta = 0, gamma = 1.0, delta = 1.0)
#[1]  1.4600308688 -0.0004999279  1.9301805374 -1.3276383194  0.9137183709
```

It does require also knowing how to use the ellipsis-mechanism for passing lists of arbitrary length to functions as Roland had additionally commented. The print mechanism will not actually create a data-vector of values. To do that you would need to assign (`"<-"`) the result "outside" the function body (and so the `print()` call is not needed either).

```
 library(stabledist )
 my_fun <- function(function_from_library, ...)
 {
   function_from_library <- match.fun(function_from_library)
   function_from_library(...)     }

 some_data <- my_fun ( rstable, 5, alpha = 1.7, beta = 0, gamma = 1.0, delta = 1.0)
 some_data
 # 5 random values are printed at console.
```